# Ionic Google Map Marker won't appear in android device but appears in the browser

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-maps-markers

I'm using Ionic 3. I tried running my app in the browser and the markers can be seen. When I run it in my android device, only the current location was marked. Any answers why it wasn't found in my android device? It worked perfectly in my browser.

```
displayGoogleMap() {


//get current location
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {


  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);

  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapContainer.nativeElement, mapOptions);
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: latLng
  });
  this.addInfoWindow(marker, 'Current Location');


}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
});
```

}
my displayGoogleMap() works but when I'll add multiple markes, it doesn't appear already.

addMarkersToMap(bank) {

```
  console.log('bank: '+bank['id']+'lat: '+bank['address']['latitude']+' longi: '+bank['address']['longitude']);

  let position = new google.maps.LatLng(bank['address']['latitude'], bank['address']['longitude']);

  let mapOptions = {
    center: position,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapContainer.nativeElement, mapOptions);
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: position
  });
  this.addInfoWindow(marker, bank['institution']);
```

}

addInfoWindow(marker, content){
    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
      infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });
  }

retrieveBloodBanks(){

```
var secret='aaaaaaaaaaaa';

  // return new Promise(resolve => {

  this.http.get('http://asdfghjk.aaa.aa.aa/api/institutions?secret='+secret)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {

      this.bankList = data;
      console.log( 'rtvr bank:  '+this.bankList);

      for (let bank of this.bankList['institutions']) {
          console.log(bank['id']);
          this.addMarkersToMap(bank);
      }

    });
  // });
```

}
You're a big help to my thesis if you could help me.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

You, need to remove map option in addMarkersToMap() function,

```
addMarkersToMap(bank) {

  console.log('bank: '+bank['id']+'lat: '+bank['address']['latitude']+' longi: '+bank['address']['longitude']);

  let position = new google.maps.LatLng(bank['address']['latitude'], bank['address']['longitude']);

  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: position
  });

  this.addInfoWindow(marker, bank['institution']);
}
```